# how to write this query of many-to-many base in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey guys
I'm new to rails, There's a lot of eye-opener for me, and I write some code and it seems no efficient, I paste my code below, could you help me find a better way to write this.

videos table:

```
class CreateVideos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :videos do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :desc
      t.string :tudou
      t.string :otherurl

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :videos
  end
end
```

drummers table:

```
class CreateDrummers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :drummers do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :middle_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :nick_name
      t.boolean :gender

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :drummers
  end
end
```

and I set them to simple many-to-many association

```
class CreateDrummersVideosJoin < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :drummers_videos, :id => false do |t|
    t.integer "drummer_id" 
    t.integer "video_id"
    end
  end


  def self.down
    drop_table :drummers_videos
  end
end
```

I want to find all the title of drummer first name is "Jojo" last name is "Mayer"'s video

my code:

```
title = Drummer.where(:first_name => "Jojo", :last_name => "Mayer").first.videos.each {|t| t.title}
```

This return all the column's data, not the only the title I want

and since the there's only one result return named "Jojo Mayer", But the return value is activeRelation, I can't call videos, so my work around is using :first to get the video instance in order to call the videos. I know it's definitely not the way doing it

any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a join table in between them like you infer. But that join table in Rails does not have to be created in a migration. It can be done exclusively in the models.

```
#drummer.rb
 belongs_to  :drummer_videos, :polymorphic => true
 has_many    :videos, :as => :drummer_videos

#video.rb
 belongs_to :drummer_videos, :polymorphic => true
 has_many :drummers, :as => :drummer_videos
```

Make sure that the `drummer TABLE` and `video TABLE` have a `drummer_videos_id` attribute.

Then you can call your Drummer..

```
Drummer.where(:first_name => "Jojo", :last_name => "Mayer").videos.each {|t| t.title}
```

Comment: Hey Trip, as far as I know there only two ways to do the many-to-many relationship,Your solution seems new to me, Where can I find the reference about all this association, thanks

Comment: Here's a great railscast on it http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association

Answer (score 1):

First off, if you want to get only the title attribute from the videos you should use map or collect instead of each, so something like this:

```
Drummer.where(...).first.videos.map{ |t| t.title }
```

or even shorter:

```
.map(&:title)
```

Second, it seems to me that if you really want to get all the videos from a single Drummer object, than using first in some way or another, like you do, is a pretty good option.

Otherwise, if you want to get all videos from different Drummers according to a certain criteria, then you should probably call Video directly and then join or include the Drummer. Perhaps like this:

```
Video.joins(:drummers).where("drummers.first_name = 'jojo' AND drummers.last_name = 'Mayer'").map(&:title)
```

Comment: Danne, you are good! Can you recommend some Rails tuts or other learning material to me? Thanks

Comment: Thanks! I started with RoR about a year ago and in the beginning, I just followed one of the million results you get from googling Ruby on Rails Tutorial. But as I progressed I found that for me the best ideas came from looking here at StackOverflow to see what other people where asking about and the answers they got.

Comment: Great, Thanks for sharing your experience