# which is the better way to do many-to-many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey, everyone, in my last question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365183/how-to-write-this-query-of-many-to-many-base-in-rails), In the answer which is given by Trip, he said:

> But that join table in Rails does not
>   have to be created in a migration. It
>   can be done exclusively in the models.

should I use a join table like my code or without join table by using :though? Which is the right way to go?

Comment: he has given the best solution .... at least for me it is ... By the way , there is no right way ... to achieve a thing in rails , you have many different good ways ...

Comment: my advise ... just try both and you will know it ...

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the requirement. See, primarily you should go with [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001319) as it does not need an extra model.

But if you need any other extra information to be saved in the table also along with association, then you must go with [has_many :through](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001316) option